# In AngularJS, how do I get one factory function to refer to another?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

For example, in the following code I would like func2 to call func1.

```
App.factory("MyLib", function() {

  return {

    func1: function() {
      console.log("func1");
    },

    func2: function() {
      func1();
    }

  }

});
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Just like with normal javascript object: `this.func1()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The safest way is to use the revealing module pattern:

```
App.factory("MyLib", function() {

    var func1 = function() {
        console.log("func1");
    };

    var func2 = function() {
        func1();
    };

    return {
        func1: func1,
        func2: func2
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually assign it to a variable name same as factory for easier reading and useful to reuse it when you have nested function as show in the example below.

```
App.factory("MyLib", function() {
    var MyLib = {
        func1: function() {
            console.log("func1");
        },
        func2: function() {
            MyLib.func1();
            angular.forEach(["1","2"], function(value, key) {
                //easier to read and understand
                MyLib.func1();
            },[]);
        }
    }
    return MyLib;
});
```